# Analytical Query in SQL for MIN, MAX, and AVG

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out a query for this question: for each major, list the number of students, minimum GPA, maximum GPA, average GPA, minimum age, maximum age, and average age. (Show GPA with 2 decimal points, age with no decimal points. You may find it useful to create a view with one of the previous queries for this one.)

This is the script to create the table for SQL!

```
REM drop all the tables. Note that you need to drop the
REM dependent table first before dropping the base tables.

drop table Reg;
drop table Student;
drop table Course;

REM Now create all the tables.

create table Student
(
    sid char(10) primary key,
    sname varchar(20) not null, 
    gpa float, 
    major char(10), 
    dob DATE
);

create table Course
(
    cno char(10) primary key,
    cname varchar(20) not null, 
    credits int, 
    dept char(10)
);

create table Reg
(
    sid references Student(sid) on delete cascade,  
    cno references Course(cno) on delete cascade,  
    grade char(2),  
    primary key (sid, cno)
);

REM Now insert all the rows.

insert into Student values ('111', 'Joe', 3.5 , 'MIS', '01-AUG-2000');
insert into Student values ('222', 'Jack', 3.4  , 'MIS', '12-JAN-1999');
insert into Student values ('333', 'Jill', 3.2 , 'CS', '15-MAY-1998');
insert into Student values ('444', 'Mary', 3.7 , 'CS', '17-DEC-2001');
insert into Student values ('555', 'Peter', 3.8 , 'CS', '19-MAR-1999');
insert into Student values ('666', 'Pat', 3.9,  'Math', '31-MAY-2000');
insert into Student values ('777', 'Tracy', 4.0,  'Math', '18-JUL-1997');

insert into Course values ('c101', 'intro', 3 , 'CS');
insert into Course values ('m415', 'database', 4 , 'Bus');
insert into Course values ('m215', 'programming', 4 , 'Bus');
insert into Course values ('a444', 'calculus', 3 , 'Math');

insert into Reg values ('111', 'c101', 'A');
insert into Reg values ('111', 'm215', 'B');
insert into Reg values ('111', 'm415', 'A');
insert into Reg values ('222', 'm215', 'A');
insert into Reg values ('222', 'm415', 'B');
insert into Reg values ('333', 'c101', 'A');
insert into Reg values ('444', 'm215', 'C');
insert into Reg values ('444', 'm415', 'B');
insert into Reg values ('555', 'c101', 'B');
insert into Reg values ('555', 'm215', 'A');
insert into Reg values ('555', 'm415', 'A');
insert into Reg values ('666', 'c101', 'A');
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT major,      
  count(distinct SID) as students,      
  round(min(gpa), 2),      
  round(max(gpa), 2),      
  round(avg(gpa), 2),      
  trunc(min(sysdate - dob)/365) as min_age,      
  trunc(max(sysdate - dob)/365) as max_age,      
  trunc(avg(sysdate - dob)/365) as avg_age, 
FROM Student 
GROUP BY MAJOR;
```

Comment: It's great that you've provided the table definitions and sample data!  What have you tried already and what about that query isn't working?  We're happy to help students learn but we generally don't want to do the entire question for you.

Comment: Also, why analytic, rather than aggregate?

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, of course, I understand that! So this is what I have so far: `SELECT major, 
    count(distinct SID) as students, 
    round(min(gpa), 2), 
    round(max(gpa), 2), 
    round(avg(gpa), 2), 
    trunc(min(sysdate - dob)/365) as min_age, 
    trunc(max(sysdate - dob)/365) as max_age, 
    trunc(avg(sysdate - dob)/365) as avg_age,
FROM Student
GROUP BY MAJOR;` I am getting the average age wrong but I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. If you can please assist me with this? Thank you!!

Comment: @Marce - please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66355835/edit) to add that code so it can be formatted properly. Can you also show the result you get now and your expected result (as text too), and why you think the results are wrong? [They don't look obviously incorrect.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=58c891f41e85b3e198479564be1a1a8e)

Comment: @AlexPoole Okay I did!!

Comment: @AlexPoole I figured it out :) my avg_age was wrong because it had to be  `round(avg(sysdate - dob)/365) as avg_age`

Comment: @Marce sorry, didn’t see your comment first. You have already hot your answer. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

According to your input I've made a query that I belive will show you the results. (It was kind hard to read the tables the way you posted it). The syntax may differ according to your DBMS (SQL Server, MySQL, REdshift, Postgres, etc)

Here is the query:

```
SELECT major,
 COUNT(*) as students,
 ROUND(MIN(gpa), 2) as min_gpa,
 ROUND(MAX(gpa), 2) as max_gpa,
 ROUND(AVG(gpa), 2) as avg_gpa,
 MIN(DATEDIFF(year, current_date, dob)) as min_age,
 MAX(DATEDIFF(year, current_date, dob)) as max_age,
 AVG(DATEDIFF(year, current_date, dob)) as avg_date
 FROM students st left join Course co on co.dept = st.major
GROUP BY major
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, I've been getting some errors in Oracle LiveSQL :(

Answer (score 0):

Your query is completely fine (just remove comma(,) after avg_age.

```
SELECT major,      
  count(distinct SID) as students,      
  round(min(gpa), 2)  as MinGPA,      
  round(max(gpa), 2)  as MaxGPA,      
  round(avg(gpa), 2)  as AvgGPA,      
  round(min(sysdate - dob)/365,0) as min_age,      
  round(max(sysdate - dob)/365,0) as max_age,      
  round(avg(sysdate - dob)/365,0) as avg_age
FROM Student 
GROUP BY MAJOR;
```

You can also use months_between() with floor() to get the same result:

```
select * from student;
SELECT major,      
  count(distinct SID) as students,      
  round(min(gpa), 2) as MinGPA,      
  round(max(gpa), 2) as MaxGPA,      
  round(avg(gpa), 2) as AvgGPA,
  floor(min(months_between(trunc((sysdate)), dob)) /12) as min_age,      
  floor(max(months_between(trunc((sysdate)), dob)) /12) as max_age,      
  floor(avg(months_between(trunc((sysdate)), dob)) /12) as avg_age
  
  
FROM Student 
GROUP BY MAJOR;
```